# send data to element from component cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Is it possible to pass some data to an element inside a component in cakephp by calling `$this->element('path_to_element', $data);` or something?

Anybody let me know please

Answer (score 0):

You can set a view var from the component if you keep a reference to the Controller. Then inside your view you would pass that view var to the element.

You can use one of the methods found here http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/996/Creating-Components#MVC-Class-Access-Within-Components-998 to keep a reference to the controller then when you need to just `$this->ControllerReference->set('viewVarName', 'data')`

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way out for this.I have been using this trick for all my projects.Make use of session in you project. Make it active.

Here in sample element.You can use layout.ctp to write session or your selectef controller.Below i am using cakephp auth session.Enjoy.Hope it will solve your problem  :)

```
<?php if($this->Session->check('Auth.user')){ ?>

        <span id="uname_wel">Welcome <?php echo $session->read('Auth.user.username'); ?></span>

<?php } ?>
```

Otherwise you can check this link [here](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/en/view/1082/Passing-Variables-into-an-Element)

OR 
If you are loading element from a view then you can pass data to view as usual,and then you can acceess from inside your element page....
eg:`$this->set('result_array',$data);`

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood, you can pass an array of values in, all you need to do is this:

```
echo $this->element('myelement', array(
    'myvar1' => $myvarvalue, 
    'myvar2' => $myvarvalue2));
```

Then inside your element's code you can access $myvar1 and $myvar2.

Hope this helps.